# no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' and 'Word')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I got the following compiler error: `no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' and 'Word')`

What is the cause of this error?

Below is a minimal example to reproduce the errror:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

struct Word
{
    char word[10];
    char mean[20];
};

Word word;

void writeDataToFile()
{
    std::fstream fileOutput("data.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    // error handling left out for simplicity
    fileOutput << word << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    strcpy(word.word, "Apple");
    strcpy(word.mean, "Trai tao");
    writeDataToFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: your `fileOutput << a << endl; ` is trying to use a non-existent operator. Only you know what that operator should look like, and should be the one writing it. See [Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2):

You need to overload the output operator for struct `Word` since you are using it on line `fileOutput << a << endl;`. Check out these two links on [output overloading on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm) and [operator overloading on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream).